# How would I get the average number of "child" records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Survey` model and each survey `has_many questions` and each `question belongs_to survey`.

What I'm trying to do is find the average number of questions each survey has.

What's the easiest way to pull that off?

I'm running Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a `questions_count` column on the `surveys` table which can be used to cache this number. This could be done automatically if you had specified the `belongs_to :survey` in your `Question` model like this:

```
belongs_to :survey, :counter_cache => true
```

But now that you've actually got surveys and questions, you're going to need to create this column and then in a migration update the count to be correct:

```
def up
  add_column :surveys, :questions_count, :integer, :default => 0
  Survey.all.each do |survey|
    survey.questions_count = survey.questions.count
    survey.save
  end
end
```

Then, once you've got this column, it's a simple ARel query to find the average:

```
Survey.average(:questions_count)
```

In addition to this, you can now get the questions count automatically without having to do another query on the questions table after you load the surveys. This would be greatly helpful if you want to display this somewhere.